# Transcendental Extensions are of the type $K(x_{1}, \ldots , x_{n})$?

Tags: field-theory

Let $K \mid L$ be a transcendental field extension. Even more, suppose that the transcendental degree of $K$ over $L$ is $n$. Is it true that we can find $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in K$ in such a manner that $K \cong L(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n})$?

Comment: What are $F$ and $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Not true if you only meant "transcendental extensions."  True if you meant "purely transcendental extensions."  For example, $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is a transcendental extension of $\mathbb{R}$ with transcendental degree $1$, but $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}(x)$.